# How to keep NavigationController when performSegue from embeded tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar, uistoryboard

In the bottom left viewcontroller i have a searchbar at the top that call the tableview at the top , the problem is that i want to segue to the right viewcontroller with detail of it, but of course i'm losing my navigationController so when i'm into the right viewcontroller i can't go back anymore, how should i do to go back to my original Viewcontroller ?

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you are doing a segue. Instead you should be pushing the new ViewController so it comes in the stack of the NavigationController. If you do "present" as your segue you will always have this effect

Answer (score 0):

Add Navigation Controller as the starting view in storyboard. And then Link RootViewController to it. This will ensure navigation bar in all the views coming next.

you may hide navigation bar in the view where not needed as

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

**push newViewController instead of presenting**

Also please check, if you are presenting it modally. Modal segues take over the whole screen, so any navigation bars, tool bars, or tab bars that are in the presenting controller will be covered up. If you want a navigation bar on this modal controller, you'll need to add one specifically to it, and add any buttons you want to that new navigation bar (or tool bar). If you don't want to do this, then don't present it modally, do a push to it.

[image: Navigation Controller to RootViewController]

Comment: Sorry, there's already a viewcontroller, the problem is that the view at the top is only here to display the tableView i need for my searchbar at the root viewcontroller, 

you can't see it but i'm using a big title and searchbar added to it, the problme is that since my tableview is kind of embeded and disconnected from the rest, i don't have a navigation when performing my segue

Comment: may you please show screenshot from start of the storyboard ? Do you mean Navigation controller from viewcontroller (already a viewcontroller). Do you already have navigation bar in other view ?

Comment: Also please check --> Your segue must be connected to the SecondViewController's NavigationController.  Is it already like this ?

Comment: Which segue must be connected to which navigationController ?

Comment: segue must be connected to NavigationController whose navigationBar is missing.  Segue that loads corresponding view

Comment: So i need to connect my tableview controller view to another view or navigationcontroller ? even if it's just an embeded view called in a UISearchController ?

Comment: Connect your TableViewController to nextView's NavigationController. Also please check, if you are presenting it modally. Modal segues take over the whole screen, so any navigation bars, tool bars, or tab bars that are in the presenting controller will be covered up. If you want a navigation bar on this modal controller, you'll need to add one specifically to it, and add any buttons you want to that new navigation bar (or tool bar). If you don't want to do this, then don't present it modally, do a push to it.

Comment: Also please present the view as push, do present modally to avoid all these issues.   It seems you are presenting tableview modally, please change it to push